# Jquery post: handling $_POST checkboxes with foreach loop?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, foreach

On its own, this php works for deleting multiple values when the (controlpanel.php) input html name is "checkbox[]", **however I'm not sure how to deal with these $_POST values using jquery**? I tried putting "checkbox[]" on the id but that didn't work. When I tried vardump($_POST) I just got the same value each time no matter how many checkboxes were ticked.

test_process.js

```
$('#delete_submit').on('click', function(event) {
    alert("Test");
    event.preventDefault();
    var delete_value = $('#checkbox').val();
    $.post('ajax/name.php', {delete_template: delete_value}, function(data) {
        $('div#delete_data').text(data);
   });      
});
```

ajax/name.php

```
<?php
include('C:\xampp\htdocs\email1\class\db.php');
require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\email1\config\db.php');
require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\email1\class\Login.php');

$login = new Login();
$user = $_SESSION['user_name'];
$db = new Database();
$db->connect();

    //delete
if (isset($_POST['delete_template'])) {
foreach($_POST as $value){
        $db->delete('templates','template_name="'.$value.'"');
        echo $value. " has been successfully deleted.";
}
}
```

Controlpanel.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<form action="ajax/name.php" name="delete_template_form" id="delete_template_form" method="post">
<?php print "<table border=\"1\">
<th>Template Name</th>
<th>Template Description</th>
<th> </th>";
foreach($res as $row){ 
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>". $row['template_name']. "</td>";
echo "<td>". $row['template_description']. "</td>";
echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" value=".$row['template_name']." name=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox\"></td>";
echo "<tr/>"; 
} 
print "</table>"; ?>
<br/><button type="button" name="delete_submit" id="delete_submit">Delete</button>
</form>
<div id="delete_data"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="test_process.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` are supposed to be unique, and since you are using the same `id` for every checkbox -> `id=\"checkbox\"`, `var delete_value = $('#checkbox').val();` will only select the 1st instance of `id=\"checkbox\"`.

1- change your checkboxes to an array (`name=\"checkbox[]\"`) and your `id`s to something unique (`id=\"checkbox".$row['id']."`) -

```
echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" value=".$row['template_name']." name=\"checkbox[]\" id=\"checkbox".$row['id']."\"></td>";
```

2- change your javascript to serializing your form inputs and send that as your data `$('#delete_template_form').serialize()` -

```
$.post('ajax/name.php', $('#delete_template_form').serialize() , function(data) {
      $('div#delete_data').text(data);
});
```

3- then in your php, loop through your checkboxes

```
if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $value){
        $db->delete('templates','template_name="'.$value.'"');
        echo $value. " has been successfully deleted.";
}
```

Comment: This works great apart from the jquery.serialize method which doesn't allow the whole template name to go through when there's a space.

Comment: That is because you have improper syntax in your html. Your value attribute needs to be encapsulated in quotes. Change `value=".$row['template_name']."` to `value=\"".$row['template_name']."\"` or `value='".$row['template_name']."'`